# XMPPFramework - Sending Group Chat Message in iOS Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using XMPPFramework in iOS. I send a message like so:

```
<message type="groupchat" to="groupname@conference.im.xx.cn">
  <x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
    <offline/>
    <delivered/>
    <displayed/>
    <composing/>
  </x>
  <body>&lt;Message FontName='宋体' FontSize='200' FontColr='0' FontBold='0'&gt;asdf&lt;/Message&gt;</body>
</message>
```

But I get the following error result:

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" to="154191@im.xx.cn/1e840910" from="groupname@conference.im.xx.cn">
  <x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
    <offline/>
    <delivered/>
    <displayed/>
    <composing/>
  </x>
  <body>&lt;Message FontName='宋体' FontSize='200' FontColr='0' FontBold='0'&gt;asdf&lt;/Message&gt;</body>
  <error code="406" type="modify">
    <not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></not-acceptable>
  </error>
</message>
```

Comment: Hello, could you share on how to output this XML message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem by myself .

You have to send XMPPPresence to that chatroom first .

Comment: Can you please tell how did you accomplish this in a bit more detail? I'm stuck with the same thing.

Comment: Hello @dee, How did you send presence with message ? I am getting same error while sending message in a group.

Comment: @Sushil  , try to send XMPPPresence to that chat room first .

Comment: @dee, Thanks for reply. Can you please help me with some code please ?

Comment: @Weizhi Can you please share the code? I am stuck with occupant error.

Comment: @Weizhi How we send the XMPPresence ? can you share the code please.

Comment: ```
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
[presence addChild:[DDXMLNode elementWithName:@"status" stringValue:@"I am online."]];
[presence addChild:[DDXMLNode elementWithName:@"show" stringValue:@"some value"]];

[self.stream sendElement:presence];
```

Check if this can help :)